# flash socket policy with nodejs and expressjs

Tags: node.js, express

I have small application on nodejs + expressjs + socket.io and it works like a charm... mostly.

There is problem with flash [socket policy server](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/socket_policy_files.html). Thing is that I cannot run socket policy server on port 843. If Flash Player cannot retrieve a master policy file from port 843, then it requests a socket policy file on the port where it is trying to connect. So the solution could be on 80 respond to normal http request (with express) and on the same port catch plain TCP connection with data `<policy-file-request/>\0` and respond with policy. I was trying adapt [this code](https://gist.github.com/mattcg/489841) but without luck.

How force express to respond with policy for TCP connection when `<policy-file-request/>\0` is incoming and serve http response otherwise?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is possible with the socket.io Flash movie, but you could explicitly set a port to load the policy file from.

From the point of an ActionScript 3 developer you could do:

```
Security.loadPolicyFile("xmlsocket://example.com:10843");
socket = new FlashSocket("example.com:80");
```

This way it is possible to load the `crossdomain.xml` from a other port then your HTTP port or 843.

Comment: Running flash policy server on port other that 843 not gonna work for me.
1. It does not resolve problem because a big amount of users is behind proxy (corporation) and they have usually only port 80 443 available. Big issue for users.
2. I can only use port 80, 443. Big issue for me.

Solution is run server on port 80 and recognize if it is raw TCP connection for flash policy file or HTTP. But I don't know how do it in node with epress.